# Url rewriting and redirrecting not working (quite)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a WordPress installation in my main folder, so my site goes like

```
www.example.com
```

Besides that I have a subfolder with a separate static site that you can access with

```
www.example.com/special
```

So in the special pages I have a page called

```
www.example.com/special/my-special-page
```

It's actually a `.php` file, but I've removed the extensions in the `.htaccess` file of that special site with this

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

And this works.

But my client said: I want, when I enter

```
www.example.com/myawardspage
```

to go to

```
www.example.com/special/my-special-page
```

but to have the above URL (without `/special/my-special-page`) in it. So in the main `.htaccess` file (the one that controls the WordPress) I've added

```
RewriteRule ^myawardspage?$ http://www.example.com/special/my-special-page [NC,L]
```

So now when you go to

```
www.example.com/myawardspage
```

I am redirected to

```
www.example.com/special/my-special-page
```

which is great, but I need the URL to look like

```
www.example.com/myawardspage
```

So in the `.htaccess` file of the special page I've added

```
RewriteRule ^myawardspage/?$ /special/my-special-page [NC]
```

But the URL remains the same (`http://www.example.com/special/my-special-page`).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do you want to achieve that when ever www.example.com/myawardspage entered, you want to pull data from http://www.example.com/special/my-special-page. Means to show your entered URL but data from http://www.example.com/special/my-special-page ... am I right ?

Comment: Yeah when you enter `www.example.com/myawardspage` the content from the `www.example.com/special/my-special-page` will be shown (what I've acchieved), but the url in the browser must be  `www.example.com/myawardspage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you mean when ever you want to hit `www.example.com/myawardspage` then you want to get data from `www.example.com/special/my-special-page` while in your address bar your address remains `www.example.com/myawardspage` To achieve this apply this rule in your **WordPress installation's** `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteRule    ^myawardspage/?$    www.example.com/special/my-special-page    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "www.example.com/special/my-special-page"
```

It wil get you desired data and your problem will be solved. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Ok, so your rule almost worked. As you wrote it didn't work but I put `RewriteRule ^myawardspage/?$ /special/my-special-page [NC,L]` and that almost worked - I got the content from the page, and the url is like I need it, but the layout is all messed up and I got bunch of errors in my console. The style issue solves when I put the `style.css` from my special folder to my root folder where my `wp-content` is located. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, my rule was just for elaboration purposes to give you total control and so you got the point that's why we are here. So, now all other static content of your website must have there proper styles and js files if any so that you can show what you want to .... The purpose of .htaccess is to just redirect or get your content to show with your desired URL format, all other styles and js related content will be done as normally did in WordPress and Static website. Hope you got it.

Comment: So this just shows the content, but it won't fetch the styling located in the `special/` folder? Other than copying the style from the special page to the root of my wordpress installation, there is not much else I can do, right?

Comment: make sure your site page which are showing data is styled properly, I mean is that page it self showing well ??? Otherwise there should not be any issue in this code, as I tested is thoroughly and it works fine.

Comment: @laraib - you can't include the domain in the rule itself. `RewriteRule` in the htaccess context only sees the `REQUEST_URI` without the leading slash. So your rule won't work, unless `www.example.com` is a directory, which it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Just below `RewriteEngine on`, place the following lines in your `/.htaccess` (document root) file:

```bash
# Check if the file being requested exists
# in the 'special' directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/special/$1.php -f

# If so, then rewrite accordingly:
RewriteRule ^([^.]+) special/$1.php [L]
```

Using this method means that you don't need that rule in the `special/.htaccess` file - you can safely remove it.

Comment: This is just for removing `.php` extension, right? But that's not the issue :D

Comment: I think the only problem with my answer is that it doesn't account for the change in name, ie. you want `special/my-specialpage.php` to be served when you request `myawardspage`. Is that correct? I simply understood the question as: your client wants to omit the `special/` when serving existing files from that directory without the extension. Apologies if I misunderstood...

Comment: Yeah, no problem, your answer is good, but for a thing I solved :)